# Jquery wrapInner not working on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some issues with wrapInner that I've never seen before. The page is a dynamically generated page, which is expected, and I'm trying to wrap all the elements of an div in a table for a grid.

Here's an example of the HTML code:

```
<div class="n-files-all" id="yw4">
    <div class="yiiPager">
        <div class="n-file">content</div>
        <div class="n-file">content</div>
        <div class="n-file">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's the javascript:

```
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
    if ( icon_container.find(".n-file").length ) {
        // if there are children, do this
        console.log("There are n-files!");
        $(".n-files-all .yiiPager").wrapInner("<table id='myGrid' class='tablesorter'></table>");
        clearInterval(checkExist);
    }
}, 100);
```

It's going into the if block because I can put in send logs to the console and I can see it there.

I'm trying to end up with this which should be pretty simple (I would eventually wrap the inner elements in tr and td):

```
<div class="n-files-all" id="yw4">
    <div class="yiiPager">
        <table id="myGrid" class="tablesorter">
            <div class="n-file">content</div>
            <div class="n-file">content</div>
            <div class="n-file">content</div>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the kicker, if i copy and paste the code into the console, it works and does what I want it to. What could be going on? The setInterval should work by waiting for the content, but I also tried $( document ).ready() to wait for the whole document to load.

Thanks in advance!

**More Info:**

So I if I append or prepend plain text into the div it works. but If I try to prepend or append anything with html, it will not, it'll strip out the HTML and leave just the text.

Comment: What does `icon_container.length` evaluate to at the `if` block? Maybe it's being defined before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Which code part works when copied? The whole thing including the setInterval?

Comment: It evaluates to 3, or to how many children is in the div. Thanks.

Comment: This part works, minus the setInterval code:

`if ( icon_container.find(".n-file").length ) {

        console.log("There are n-files!");

        $(".n-files-all .yiiPager").wrapInner("<table id='myGrid' class='tablesorter'></table>");

    }`

Answer (score 0):

what if you change the:

```
if ( icon_container.find(".n-file").length ) {
```

to

```
if ( $('#yw4 .yiiPager .n-file').length > 0 ) {
```

anyway the original seems to be valid, if we assume that the icon_container is properly defined.

Comment: Doesn't work :/ Other js works but I can't use wrapInner on anything.

Comment: this works for me if I add the following `var icon_container = $("#yw4");` before the `var checkExist = setInterval(function() {` line